# Example of using Undertow’s text based handler configuration format

Tags: java, reverse-proxy, undertow

According to [the spec](http://undertow.io/documentation/core/predicates-attributes-handlers.html) there is a nice text based configuration for Undertow.

However I don't see a single line of example code how to boot Undertow with such configuration.

How to use `Undertow.builder()...` to build Undertow server with text configuration.

I'm trying to do something like

```
path-prefix['/api'] -> reverse-proxy[{'http://myserver.com'}]
path-prefix['/*'] -> serve-static-files-here-somehow
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`PredicatedHandlersParser`](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/1.1.1.Final/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/handlers/builder/PredicatedHandlersParser.java) and the associated [test case](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/1.1.1.Final/core/src/test/java/io/undertow/server/handlers/PredicatedHandlersTestCase.java).